# Comparing all elements of an array and XElement

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with comparing all elements of an array to all elements of an XElement object that I go through with a "for" loop. I need to check if the second structure has the element from the first one, if the first one has an element, that is not in the second structure, I will need to add it. It should work like this: Check if the strings in the loop contain a specific fragment that indicates, that they are the same object, if not, go into another loop/"if" or whatever.

I use .Contains() to find the string fragment, that indicates, that they are the same.
The first object is an array[30], partially filled with strings.
The second object is an "Name" XElement, that i get using a "for" loop like this:

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(folderName1 + "\\" + TXTFiles[i]);
IEnumerable<XElement> objectList = doc1.Descendants("ObjectList");
IEnumerable<XElement> HmiTag = objectList.Elements("Hmi.Tag.Tag");
for (int f = 0; f < HmiTag.Count(); f++)
{
IEnumerable<XElement> Name = HmiTag.ElementAt(f).Descendants("Name");
if (!(Name.ElementAt(0).ToString().Contains("Zone" + nbr + "_Pallet_Transfer") && !(array[ ].Contains("Zone" + nbr + "_Pallet_Transfer")) // something like that
}
```

The array includes:

```
Zone3_Pallet_Transfer,
Zone1_Pallet_Transfer,
Zone5_Pallet_Transfer,
```

The "Name" includes:

```
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{0},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{1},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{2},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{3},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{4},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{5},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{6},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{7},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{8},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{9},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{10},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{11},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{12},
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Zone3_Pallet_Transfer,
DB10000_Zone2_Data_Zone1_Pallet_Transfer,
```

and should also include DB10000_Zone2_Data_Zone5_Pallet_Transfer, found in the array.

Comment: Try following : List<string> tags = objectList.Elements("Hmi.Tag.Tag").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();

Comment: you want to add all elements of first list which are not in second list DB100000_....? and element added must follow the format ZoneX_Pallet_Transfert?

Comment: I want to only look at the pattern "ZoneX_Pallet_Transfer", so the Zone2_Data_Pallet_Transfer{X} stay untouched., i.e.: if the array has Zone5_Pallet_Transfer, but the "Name" XElement structure doesn't have the "DB10000_Zone2_Data_ZoneX_Pallet_Transfer", then it should be added. My biggest concern is finding the differences.